# MySQL copy data from one table to another in different fields

Tags: mysql, sql, bulkinsert

**user table**:
id | facebookid | externalid | more data...

**userexternalid table**:
id | userid | facebookid | externalid

What I need is to write a query that gets all data from the user table and inserts is as following for every single row.

```
userexternalid.userid = user.id
userexternalid.facebookid = user.facebookid 
userexternalid.externalid = user.externalid
```

Can't seem to find anything like it on the web. Anyone an idea?
Thanks

Comment: @Gunaseelan oh yes. didn't stumble across that one when I was searching. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO userexternalid (userid, facebookid, externalid) 
    SELECT id AS userid, facebookid, externalid FROM user;
```

Comment: Quite simple solution actually. I'll test it. Thanks for the fast help.